# Combine data from different sheets BUT replace content with a given variable

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RVmB7eXlgxvRqyvm2RdYDL1Si9rVBSese9v2Rh7Ytx8/edit?usp=sharing)

I have three schedules and want a merged view but content must not be displayed. Can I replace it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={"Monday"\"Tuesday"\"Wednesday"\"Thursday"\"Friday"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(
 IF(C2:G7<>""; B1&", "; )&
 IF(C10:G15<>""; B9&", "; )&
 IF(C18:G23<>""; B17; ); ", $"; ))}
```

[image: 0]